# using logfile when installing .exe with powershell

Tags: powershell, dockerfile, exe

When I want to install an .msi file with powershell and want to use logging I use the following code:

```
RUN Invoke-WebRequest http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/1/D/01DC28EA-638C-4A22-A57B-4CEF97755C6C/WebDeploy_amd64_en-US.msi -OutFile webdeploy.msi; \
Start-Process msiexec -Wait -ArgumentList '/i webdeploy.msi /l*v C:\msilog.txt /q' ; \
Remove-Item -Force webdeploy.msi
```

I searched on google how to do this for an .exe file but cannot find a solution.

So my question how do I add a log file for the following function in powerhsell:

```
RUN Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing 
https://download.microsoft.com/download/5/B/C/5BC5DBB3-652D-4DCE-B14A- 
475AB85EEF6E/vcredist_x86.exe -OutFile vcredist_x86.exe; \
powershell.exe -Command Start-Process vcredist_x86.exe -ArgumentList '/quiet' 
| Wait-Process
RUN Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing 
https://download.microsoft.com/download/9/1/4/914851c6-9141-443b-bdb4- 
8bad3a57bea9/vcredist_x64.exe -OutFile vcredist_x86.exe; \
powershell.exe -Command Start-Process vcredist_x86.exe -ArgumentList '/quiet' 
| Wait-Process
```

Comment: First hit on Google: https://xsisupport.com/2011/02/06/command-line-for-installing-vcredist/

Comment: If you're asking how to make arbitrary executables create logs, that is only possible if the executable provides a logging parameter. Otherwise the only thing you could do is redirect the output on STDOUT, but Docker should already log that by itself.

Comment: On the website it says:
/q:a /T:%windir%\temp /c:"VCREDI~2.EXE /q:a
 /c:""msiexec /i vcredist.msi /qn /l*v %temp%\vcredist_x64_2005.log"" "


But how do I apply that to my powershell command.

Comment: The website shows a command (`vcredeist_x64.exe`) with a parameter list (`/q:a ...`). So ask yourself: how might one integrate that with `Start-Process -ArgumentList`?

Comment: I did:

        RUN Invoke-WebRequest https://download.microsoft.com/download/6/D/F/6DF3FF94-F7F9-4F0B-838C-A328D1A7D0EE/vc_redist.x64.exe -OutFile vcredist_x64.exe; \
    Start-Process msiexec -Wait -ArgumentList '/i vcredist_x64.exe /l*v C:\vcredistlog.txt /q' ; \
    Remove-Item -Force vcredist_x64.exe

But doesnt seemed to be installed.

Comment: Then again, you have a `vcredist_x86.exe`, not a `vcredist_x64.exe`, don't you? And the quotes in the commandline are not optional.

Comment: what do you mean quotes are not optional. Webdeploy gets installed perfect like this (See my first post).

When I check the log of credist_x64, I see that it doesnt get installed.

I find it difficult to see what I have to improve to make it work.